# Insert element into array of array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array created this way:

```
    a=np.zeroes(3,1).
```

I want to add a new element to first array in a; I want this to be my output:
        a = np.array([1,0],[0],[0])

I've tried
        a = np.insert(a[0],0,1)
but that modifies the entire array a. Is there a way to simply add an element to a and not change it entirely? Thanks!

Comment: Numpy arrays must have the same number of elements per row. In other words, their shape must be uniform (unless you want a Numpy array of Python lists).

Comment: You do not have an "array of arrays". You have created a `numpy.ndarray`, which is a true, multidimensional array.

Comment: Think of a 2-D numpy array as a matrix. No matrix has 2 elements in the first row, and 1 element on the following rows. If you just want to store a collection of arbitrarily-sized lists, use pure python lists.